# Air html window in debugger

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash

I have this code to open an html window from air :
_win = HTMLLoader.createRootWindow();
_win.load(new URLRequest("d:/Content/testEnvironment/bin/index.html"));

this however does not open a real html window but an air window ( i think )
 my problem is that when running a swf in this window it does not pop up the error messages even though when running the real html window in IE it does .

What should i do to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: Another solution i can use if anyone knows if i can listen to the errors thrown from flash with netconnection or any other way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Navigate to function

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("d:/Content/testEnvironment/bin/index.html"));
```

This will open the urlRequest in the users default browser.

Once this is done though you will no longer be in your AIR application.

Comment: Thanks , it does solve the proble although i rather not use it , for some reason it opens a new tab on my explorer rather then a new window , i used the parameter _blank  .

Comment: That would be down to your browser handling how to open new links. Change the settings to open new pages in windows rather than tabs.